# Messaging Architecture

Tags: java, messaging

I am building a system using a Java backend (and SQL Server) that permits users to create tasks and configure those tasks to send out email reminders in advance of the due date (like 1 day before, 7 days before, etc).

My concern is that if the there is a service outage for any reason (planned or unplanned) and during that outage reminders would have been sent, how do I make sure those missed reminders are sent when the system comes back up?  (Note that no reply or acknowledgement is expected from the reminder.) The outage could be for 5 minutes or 5 days.  And I want to make sure if there is a queue of reminders being sent and the outage occurs in the middle, that no reminder is sent twice when the system comes back.

I am slightly familiar with Java Message Service, and there are optional persistent attributes as well as sync/async with JMS.  Can I use JMS to achieve this goal?  Are there other existing frameworks that will support what I want without needing to build something from scratch.  I am particularly interested in open source frameworks or implementations.

Comment: I did something similar to your request using a table to store all the email to send with a `SEND_STATUS` and a Java Job to actually do the job. Maybe can fit your needings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to reframe your requirements first:

1. Build a service to send email
2. Service must have failover recovery, in youcase if system goes down and comes back up it should still send out pending email reminders
3. You are not expecting any acknowledgements for the messages sent.

With these requirements in mind there are several ways to do it, there are number of frameworks and tools, some of them might be overengineering of your requirements. Here is my proposal:

1. Use Java Mail API to send email reminders
2. Create a table which stores reminders to be sent and update a flag after email reminder is sent
3. In case system goes down, you can resend all reminders for which flag was not set.

You can use JMS but as you only require sending guaranteed email, I would suggest to keep it simple.

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks.  that's very helpful and is likely the approach we will take.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a table in DB where I would store the last time when an email reminder is sent. When the system starts it should check the last time, compare it with the schedule and send missing emails.

Answer (score 0):

Just as counter-argument to all 'use-table-in-db' answers.

Sure you can use almost any JMS server for that. For example, [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/docs). When you need to schedule sending email, put message in queue with delay:

```
TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
msg.setText(text);
msg.setStringProperty("recipient", emailTo);
msg.setLongProperty( "_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(value, unit) );
```

Message will be delivered in time and your async message handler can send it to recipient. You can handle messages in many threads, you can send email via different smtp servers, if you want. HornetQ easily integrate with Spring.

If you set up persistence for messages, HornetQ will store it in internal database and recover queue content after reboot.

But. That adds complexity to your project, and sometimes it is not very good, so table in DB may be a better choice.

Comment: I think we are going to use the DB approach, but this one is quite interesting too.  Thanks!